# Docker daemon fails with certificate created by letsencrypt certbot

Tags: docker, ssl, registry, harbor

I've setup Harbor (a Docker private registry), and am trying to connect to it with Docker.

`sudo docker pull registry.mysite.nl/test`

But I keep getting:

```
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Head https://registry.mysite.nl/v2/test/manifests/latest: Get https://registry.mysite.nl/service/token?scope=repository%3Atest%3Apull&service=harbor-registry: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

If I go to the site using a browser everything works swimmingly, though.. Happens to all clients, on my Mac, on the localhost on that machine etc.

Any idea? -- I regenerated the certificates multiple times etc..

Edit:
The certificate I get from letsencrypt has:

CLIENT_CERT
INTERMEDIDIATE_CERT
ROOT_CERT

all in one file. Checking the cert with OpenSSL gives an error on the validation

```
➜  certs openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/ -connect registry.mysite.nl:443 
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=1 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:0
depth=1 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:0
depth=3 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 30 14:01:15 2021 GMT
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=registry.mysite.nl
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
   i:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
 2 s:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X1
   i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
```

When I REMOVE the ROOT_CERT from this file (on the server), the error goes away:

```
➜  certs openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/ -connect registry.mysite.nl:443 
CONNECTED(00000005)
depth=2 C = US, O = Internet Security Research Group, CN = ISRG Root X1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = registry.mysite.nl
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=registry.mysite.nl
   i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
 1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=R3
   i:/C=US/O=Internet Security Research Group/CN=ISRG Root X
```

But Docker (and podman) keep complaining about invalid certificates.
`x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2022-02-17T17:19:53Z is after 2016-01-12T16:41:00Z`

Comment: I got and installed a commercial certificate. -- SAME Problem! -- Ok, so it's not letsencrypt.